# Generating data from the posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, prior, posterior

Let
$$p(D \mid \mu,\sigma^2) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
where $D=(x_1\ldots x_n)$ is my data.
I imposed a normal prior on the mean as
$$\pi(\mu) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)$$
Using Bayes, I know that the posterior is 
$$p(\mu \mid D) \propto \mathcal{N}(\mu_n,\sigma_n^2)$$
where $\mu_n$ is a convex combination between the ML estimate of $\mu$ and the initial belief $\mu_0$, that is
$$\mu_n = w\mu_{ML} + (1-w)\mu_0 \tag{1}$$
$$\sigma_n^{-2} = \frac{n}{\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2}\tag{2}$$
Using any random normal generator (R,MATLAB for ex), I could generate $D$ using $\mu,\sigma^2$.

> **Question:** If possible, how do I generate $\mu \mid D$ without $\mu_n,\sigma_n$, i.e. only using the evidence $D$? I just want to compare the empirical posterior moments, $\hat{\mu}_n,\hat{\sigma}_n^2$, to the true ones in equations $(1,2)$.

Example: In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218556/interpretation-in-histogram-of-empirical-posterior-distribution), there is a posterior histogram (evaluated empirically). How do you do that ?

Comment: I do not understand the question: $\mu_n$ is sufficient for this posterior, so "knowing" $D$ is equivalent to knowing $\mu_n$.

Comment: “Using only $D$” or also the priors?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $\sigma$ is known in your case. Then, just use the R command `rnorm` to generate a random sample from a normal distribution with the corresponding parameters

```
rnorm(n, mu = mun, sigma = sigman)
```

where `mun` and `sigman` are defined by your equations.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html

If you don't know what the posterior parameters are, just check the Conjugate Prior wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution

Comment: this is not my question.. My question is how to generate $\mu \mid D$ .. that is using the data not $\mu_n,\sigma_n$.

Comment: @user21312048 Once you have the data D, and you need to have data :), just calculate the parameters of the posterior distribution, and then simulate from $\mu \mid D$, which is just a normal distribution. If you want to simulate the data $D$ too, you need to ask that too :)

Comment: you did not read my question, where i clearly mention "Using any random normal generator (R,MATLAB for ex), I could generate $D$ (and possibly the prior) using $\mu,\sigma^2$." Now, using only the data $D$, how to generate $\mu$ ?